# Rider - How to debug the returned value of an async method in a lambda expression?

Tags: .net, debugging, asynchronous, breakpoints, rider

I am using JetBrains Rider latest EAP, and I am trying to stop the debugger at an async method call inside a lambda expression to investigate its returned value **after the task has been completed**.

I can do smart step into the async method then step out where the debugger stop again at the breakpoint showing the value of the immediately returned Task object from the async method, but that is not what I am asking for, plus the many steps for the basic need.

I am asking really for the final retuned value after this Task object has completed execution or any thrown exception in between.

Any clue or guidance in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really sure but I wonder if adding the returned Task object to watches could help?

Comment: No as it is not completed/resolved at this time so I cannot investigate the result/exception plus it is harder to deal with Task objects.